# How do you pronounce $\hat{n}$?

Tags: pronunciation

I've found a symbol $\hat{n}$ in an equation, and I have no idea how to pronounce  it, and how to write it phonetic.

---

**Edit:**
I've found it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Exponential.2C_logarithm.2C_and_power

Comment: "$n$ hat" in English, I think. But how do you mean "spell it"? Pronounce it?

Comment: My lecturers usually say something along the lines of '$n$ hat'.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for my bad english. How to pronounce it?

Comment: I don't know how to tag this. We might need a new tag.

Comment: @GitGud There is a "pronunciation" tag.

Comment: @mrp Great. I didn't know it, so I assumed it didn't exist without even checking. Thanks.

Comment: I would say "$n$ hat" but I've also heard it as "$n$ roof". Maybe "roof" was a translation from a foreign language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\hat{n}$ would typically be read by an English speaker as *n hat* (the letter n and the head covering).  In IPA its pronunciation could be written as /ˈɛn hæt/.

Answer (score 5):

Everytime I've seen this notation, it was always pronounced "$n$ hat." Everone who commented seem to agree, so we can relatively safely assume that this is common pronunciation.